# Retrieve clicked list item in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using a list to populate / generate some html code dynamically as shown below,

```
        <ul>
        {% if results %}
            {% for result in results %}
                <li><a href="/accounts/evalpage/" ><strong>{{result.0}}</strong>{{result.1}}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                <li><a href="#"><strong>No Evaluations to Perform</strong></a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
```

I'm running into an issue with that if one of the list items is clicked, i need to be able to retrieve the information stored in that list item, e.g if item one is clicked i need to retrieve `{{result.0}}` and `{{result.1}}` is there a way i can retrieve this information?

List is shown below :

```
[['User1', 'InProgress'], ['User2'], ['User3'], ['User3'], ['User4']]
```

For instance, if the row containing `User1` and `InProgress` is clicked by the end user, i want to be able to have the information `User1` and `InProgress` within Django such that operations can be performed with them

Comment: what is the value of your single results object??

Comment: 2D list, storing Two strings per array

Comment: can you paste your object in an edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be clear that in order for the backend to know what object you clicked on, you need to pass that value in the URL. So, you'll need to change the definition of your "evalpage" URL to accept a parameter:

```
url(r'^accounts/evalpage/(?P<user>\w+)/$', views.evalpage, name='evalpage')
```

and the view signature:

```
def evalpage(request, user):
    ...
```

and now you can do:

```
<a href="{% url "evalpage" user=result.0 %}">...</a>
```

Comment: Any edit of the regex which allows spaces between words?

Comment: (?P<user>\w+ +\w+) allows spaces between words if anyone needs

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 <ul>
            {% if results %}
                {% for result in results %}
                    <li>
                <a href="/accounts/evalpage/" >
                    {% for item in result %}
                    <strong>{{item}}</strong>
                    {% endfor %}
                </a>
            </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>No Evaluations to Perform</strong></a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
```

Comment: How does that allow me to identify which item is clicked in Django though?

Comment: you want to know if 'User1' is clicked or 'InProgress' is clicked?

Comment: They're part of the same row, I want to know if user1 is clicked and then retrieve user1 within django

Comment: for that you have to create a new url and view too. and <a> tag will be applied on your {{item}}

Comment: Thats fine i have a new URL and View i want it to link to, i just need to be able to retrieve the item which is clicked

Comment: something like : <a href="/accounts/yourviewtohandleuser/{{item}}" >{{item}}</a>